# Need help writing SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with some data .. percentage of each students in a school with  below columns ...

```
Class | name | Percentage( % )
```

I need a SQL query to get count of students in each class with below Diff % slabs. Students who had not written exam will have NULL in `Percentage` column in source table.

```
class| 0-10% | 10%-20% | 20%-30% | >30% | Not written ( NULLS in source table)
```

Can anybody help me writing the query?

Comment: Try searching for case expression and also please look here on how to improve question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Smelling like homework that someone hasn't put any effort into.

Comment: Select t.class,t.[range] as [Percentage range], count(*) as [Count]
from (
  select   class,  
    case when abs(OilDifferencepercent) is NULL then 'Not written exam'
 when abs(OilDifferencepercent) between 0 and 10 then ' 0- 10'
    when abs(OilDifferencepercent) between 11 and 20 then '11-20'
 when abs(OilDifferencepercent) between 21 and 30 then '21-30'
    else '30 - More' end as range
  from <Table> ) t
group by t.class,t.[range] order by t.class

Comment: Will it work ? Can you please use pivot for above reversing result

Comment: Please [edit] your question rather than posting code snippet(s) in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this helps you..

```
SELECT 
CLASS, 
[0-10%]= COUNT(CASE WHEN PERCENTAGE BETWEEN 0 AND 10 THEN 1 END),
[11-20%]= COUNT(CASE WHEN PERCENTAGE BETWEEN 11 AND 20 THEN 1 END),
[21-30%]= COUNT(CASE WHEN PERCENTAGE BETWEEN 21 AND 30 THEN 1 END),
[>30%]= COUNT(CASE WHEN PERCENTAGE >30 THEN 1 END),
[NOT WRITTEN]= COUNT(CASE WHEN PERCENTAGE IS NULL THEN 1 END)
FROM [Tablename] GROUP BY CLASS
```